# Processes and semaphores in C

Tags: c

I have this question in my exam and I want to know if my answer is correct.

Consider the following program written in C language to implement a reader:

```
// to simplify the exercise, are not checked the return values ​​of calls to the operating system

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     sem_t *sem_wrt;
     int fd, readcount;
     fd=shm_open("/readcount",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
     ftruncate(fd, sizeof(int));
     readcount=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
     sem_wrt=sem_open("/write",O_CREAT ,0xFFFFFFFF,1);
     while(1) {
        readcount++;
        if (readcount==1) sem_wait (wrt);
        my_read();
        (readcount)--;
        if (readcount==0) sem_post (wrt);
     }
 }
```

After some time of using this program, it was found that the program only works properly when it is executed only by a process simultaneously.

Change the code of the program in order to provide a solution to this problem.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     sem_t *sem_wrt;
     int fd, readcount;
     fd=shm_open("/readcount",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
     ftruncate(fd, sizeof(int));
     readcount=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
     sem_wrt=sem_open("/write",O_CREAT ,0xFFFFFFFF,1);
     //sem_mutex=sem_open("/mutex",O_CREAT ,0xFFFFFFFF,1);
     while(1) {
        //sem_wait(mutex);
        readcount++;
        if (readcount==1) sem_wait (wrt);
        //sem_post(mutex);
        my_read();
        //sem_wait(mutex);
        (readcount)--;
        if (readcount==0) sem_post (wrt);
        sem_post(mutex);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int fd, readcount;
// ...
readcount=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
```

If this is the code you're using, it probably gave you a warning which you ignored.  `mmap` returns `void *`.  You should change the declaration of `readcount` to `int *`.  Also, the size of the mapping should be a multiple of the page size.  I'd be sure to re-read the manual for `mmap`, carefully read any compiler warnings, and make sure your code checks for errors.

At any rate, if `int *readcount;` refers to shared memory, the following will not work:

```
++*readcount;
```

The problem is this line is conceptually broken into a few steps:

1. Fetch `*readcount` into register
2. Increment register
3. Store back into `*readcount`.

If multiple processes perform steps 1/2/3 in lockstep, and the initial value is 0, they will both store 1 back.

You could use a GCC extension for [compare and swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) to make an increment safe:

```
int fetch;
do
{
   fetch = *readcount;
} while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(readcount, fetch, fetch+1));
```

However I'm not sure if this will work right if you do it on memory mapped from a file by `mmap`.  Keeping this kind of atomicity in a page fault handler seems complex and I'm not sure if the standard guarantees that it should work.